# Weka ADTree classification repeated in excel

Tags: excel, machine-learning, weka

Using `Weka 3.8.0 GUI`, I have a data set (binary class) and have to make an `ADTree` model for the data. So far, so good.

```
    === Classifier model (full training set) ===

Alternating decision tree:

: 0
|  (1)vitamine_E < 0.346: -0.671
|  |  (9)oxoproline < 20.391: -0.406
|  |  (9)oxoproline >= 20.391: 0.471
|  (1)vitamine_E >= 0.346: 1.609
|  (2)glucose_1_phosphate < 0.159: -0.38
|  |  (3)ribonic_acid2 < 0.071: -1.074
|  |  |  (6)vitamine_E < 0.346: -0.937
|  |  |  (6)vitamine_E >= 0.346: 0.485
|  |  (3)ribonic_acid2 >= 0.071: 1.431
|  |  (4)inositol_put__49 < 8.363: 0.75
|  |  (4)inositol_put__49 >= 8.363: -0.788
|  |  (8)erythritol__put_ < 0.066: 0.564
|  |  (8)erythritol__put_ >= 0.066: -0.518
|  (2)glucose_1_phosphate >= 0.159: 1.407
|  |  (7)threonic_acid < 1.762: 0.885
|  |  (7)threonic_acid >= 1.762: -0.468
|  (5)glucose < 1.52: -0.298
|  (5)glucose >= 1.52: 0.884
|  |  (10)ribonic_acid2 < 0.02: -0.159
|  |  (10)ribonic_acid2 >= 0.02: 0.585
Legend: -ve = 0, +ve = 1
Tree size (total number of nodes): 31
Leaves (number of predictor nodes): 21

Time taken to build model: 0.02 seconds

=== Stratified cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correctly Classified Instances         120               92.3077 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances        10                7.6923 %
Kappa statistic                          0.8462
Mean absolute error                      0.1095
Root mean squared error                  0.2413
Relative absolute error                 21.8844 %
Root relative squared error             48.2298 %
Total Number of Instances              130
```

Then I have to repeat the classification (taken the model) in excel. So how do I do that? I already did that when I used `PART` or `SMO` algorithm, but how do I 'convert' the tree into functions for excel or read off the classification path, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Decision tree is a set of `if` functions, so you can convert your tree into ifs, like:

if (cell_of((1)vitamine_E)) < 0.346;-0.671;if ....

Comment: yes that is what I did when checking the prediction of PART f.e.; but when reading off the rules of an ADTree, don't I have to combine each leave with all other leafs? And calculate all the possible sums of the outcomes to see the prediction? That seems like horrendously much work...

Comment: Why not write a program to classify your data, and than generate an output in excel format?

Comment: I don't know how to program anything, and I have to do it in Excel besides.

Comment: Your tree contains only 31 nodes, it is not a "horrendously much work..." :)

Comment: hm... maybe i do not understand reading off the classification of ADTrees. I am reading off every possible path and calculate wheter its >0 or <0